# does an other way exist to separate WMI query results than this?

Tags: wmi

Description:
My goal is to get specific result from namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig".
Who is involved in software distribution may have knowledge or even better some others as well.
Why I ask is, when query for specific Software as you will see below, there is a minimum amount of 2 available results with one query ( guess based on its design so what ? )

How I try it:

```
     function getSWAdvertisments2 {
        Param(
            [Parameter()]
            [string] $_SWNP
        )

        $_retArr = @{}
        $prefix = ""
        $_advID = ""

        $request = "PKG_MIFName,ADV_AdvertisementID,PKG_PackageID"
        
        for ( $a=0; $a -le 1; $a++ ) {
            if ( $a -eq 0 ) { $results = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT $request FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE PKG_MIFName LIKE '%$_SWNP%'" }
            if ( $a -eq 1 ) { $results = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT $request FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE ADV_AdvertisementID='$_advID'" }

            foreach ( $result in ($results | Where-Object { $_.__CLASS = 'CCM_TaskSequence' } )) {
                $_key = (($result).PKG_MIFName).Split(' ')
                $_advID = ($result).ADV_AdvertisementID
                $_SWName = ($_key[0]).Split('-')[2]
            
                if ( $_key[1] -eq "Un" ) { $prefix = "-Remove" }
                if ( -not $_retArr.ContainsKey( $_key[0] )) {
                    $_retArr.Add( $_key[0] , $_SWName+"-"+($result).ADV_AdvertisementID+"-"+($result).PKG_PackageID )
                }
                if (( $_key[1] -eq "Un" ) -and ( $_retArr.ContainsKey( $_key[0] ))) {
                    $_retArr[$_key[0]] = $_SWName+"-"+($result).ADV_AdvertisementID+"-"+($result).PKG_PackageID+$prefix
                }
            }
        }

        return $_retArr
    }
```

this function does what i want but I tried a different way.

```
    function getSWAdvertisments {
        Param(
            [Parameter()]
            [string] $_SWNP
        )

        $_advID = ""
        Write-Host $_SWNP
        
        $request = "PKG_MIFName,ADV_AdvertisementID,PKG_PackageID,PRG_Comment"
        $_tsRes = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT $request FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE PKG_MIFName LIKE '%$_SWNP%' AND __CLASS='CCM_TaskSequence'"
        $_advID = ($_tsRes).ADV_AdvertisementID
        $_key = (($_tsRes).PKG_MIFName).Split(' ')
        $_sdRes = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT $request FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE ADV_AdvertisementID='$_advID' AND __CLASS='CCM_SoftwareDistribution'"

        $_pids = @{}
        foreach ( $_id in $_sdRes ) { $_pids.Add( ($_sdRes).PKG_PackageID, ($_sdRes).PKG_MIFName ) }

        $_retArr = @{
            'Name' = $_key[0]
            'Type' = $_key[1]
            'AppID' = ($_tsRes).PRG_Comment
            'AdvID' = ($_tsRes).ADV_AdvertisementID
            'PkgIDs' = $_pids
        }
        
        return $_retArr
    }
```

What happens in 2nd function I try to be more specific, but the results are different.
Using the same query direct on the client I got this output:

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT PKG_MIFName,ADV_AdvertisementID,PKG_PackageID,PRG_Comment FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE PKG_MIFName LIKE '%MRemoteNG%' AND __CLASS='CCM_TaskSequence'"

__GENUS             : 2
__CLASS             : CCM_TaskSequence
__SUPERCLASS        :
__DYNASTY           :
__RELPATH           :
__PROPERTY_COUNT    : 4
__DERIVATION        : {}
__SERVER            :
__NAMESPACE         :
__PATH              :
ADV_AdvertisementID : VF123366
PKG_MIFName         : COM-NextGenS-MRemoteNG-x86-176-Eng In
PKG_PackageID       : VF10176F
PRG_Comment         : 14477
PSComputerName      :

By calling the function :  getSWAdvertisments "MRemoteNG"

the only output I got is : MRemoteNG - due to i let wrote the param as output
a second example brings different result - why ?

Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\ccm\policy\machine\actualconfig" -Query "SELECT PKG_MIFName,ADV_AdvertisementID,PKG_PackageID,PRG_Comment FROM CCM_SoftwareDistribution WHERE PKG_MIFName LIKE '%Monitoring%' AND __CLASS='CCM_TaskSequence'"

__GENUS             : 2
__CLASS             : CCM_TaskSequence
__SUPERCLASS        :
__DYNASTY           :
__RELPATH           :
__PROPERTY_COUNT    : 4
__DERIVATION        : {}
__SERVER            :
__NAMESPACE         :
__PATH              :
ADV_AdvertisementID : VF123780
PKG_MIFName         : COM-MS-MonitoringAgent-x64-1020-Eng Un
PKG_PackageID       : VF101E49
PRG_Comment         : 15127
PSComputerName      :

Monitoring
{
"AppID":  "15127",
"PkgIDs":  {
"VF101E46":  "COM-MS-MonitoringAgent-x64-1020-Eng"
},
"Name":  "COM-MS-MonitoringAgent-x64-1020-Eng",
"AdvID":  "VF123780",
"Type":  "Un"
}

Comment: Mistake on my side - _sdRes should be _id in foreach ...